# What software to view EXR "videos" (single images on disk)

Tags: windows, gratis, image-viewer, live-preview

With [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) I can render my animations as single frames. When rendering as PNG, the pixel values might get clipped, so I am trying to render to an HDR format which keeps the brightness information.

Blender has an option to render as [OpenEXR [Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenEXR).

[image: Blender Output as EXR]

Watching the animation in Blender is currently a pain, since it's not smooth and lags a lot. So I need an EXR viewer which can play the EXRs smoothly. It should also provide options to adjust gamma and brightness on the fly.

The software should be gratis or open source like Blender and work on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

[DJV](https://darbyjohnston.github.io/DJV/) fits my needs. Is it Open Source, released under a BSD style license and with latest updates in 2020.

It automatically detects movie sequences from the first frame and can display FullHD videos smoothly on my machine (Ryzen 7 2700X, 32 GB RAM).

Brightness, Contrast and Saturation can be changed immediately while playing. It even supports LUTs (Lookup Tables), I just haven't figured out how to use them.

[image: DJV]

The amount of memory used for caching the pictures can be adjusted.

[image: DJV Memory amount adjustment]